# Split a field of the table up to 5 separate rows every instance of RECORD SEPARATOR CHARACTER (CHAR(30))

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently working on an Oracle SQL script that needs to split the ADDRESS field of the table below up to 5 separate rows. The said field is delimited by a record separator character (CHAR(30). I would like to ask for any recommended approach how to come up with the said data?

Please see sample data below.

```
| ID      | ADDRESS                                                |
|;--------|;-------------------------------------------------------|
| 1000000 | Xxxxx XxxxxXxxxx XxxxXxxxxx xx Xxxxxx                |
| 1000001 | 61 Xxxxxxx XxxxXxxxxxxXxxx                           |
| 1000002 | 36 Xxxxx XxxXxxxxxxxxXxxxxxxxxxxxxxXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
```

The expected output of the sample above is as follows.

```
| ID      | ADDRESS1        | ADDRESS2   | ADDRESS3         | ADDRESS4         | ADDRESS5|
|;--------|;----------------|;-----------|;-----------------|;-----------------|;--------|
| 1000000 | Xxxxx Xxxxx     | Xxxxx Xxxx | Xxxxxx xx Xxxxxx |                  |         |
| 1000001 | 61 Xxxxxxx Xxxx | Xxxxxxx    | Xxxx             |                  |         |
| 1000002 | 36 Xxxxx Xxx    | Xxxxxxxxx  | Xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   | Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |         |
```

Comment: You want to split the data in 5 rows or 5 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (id, address) as
  2    (select 1000000, 'Xxxxx Xxxxx^^Xxxxx Xxxx^^Xxxxxx xx Xxxxxx' from dual union all
  3     select 1000002, '36 Xxxxx Xxx^^Xxxxxxxxx^^Xxxxxxxxxxxxxx^^Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' from dual
  4    )
  5  select id, regexp_substr(address, '[^' ||chr(30) ||']+', 1, 1) val1,
  6             regexp_substr(address, '[^' ||chr(30) ||']+', 1, 2) val2,
  7             regexp_substr(address, '[^' ||chr(30) ||']+', 1, 3) val3,
  8             regexp_substr(address, '[^' ||chr(30) ||']+', 1, 4) val4,
  9             regexp_substr(address, '[^' ||chr(30) ||']+', 1, 5) val5
 10  from test;

        ID VAL1                 VAL2                 VAL3                 VAL4                 VAL5
---------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
   1000000 Xxxxx Xxxxx          Xxxxx Xxxx           Xxxxxx xx Xxxxxx
   1000002 36 Xxxxx Xxx         Xxxxxxxxx            Xxxxxxxxxxxxxx       Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

SQL>
```

Comment: This will not match zero-width entries where there are two successive `CHR(30)` characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple string functions (which are an order of magnitude faster than regular expressions):

```sql
SELECT id,
       CASE sep1
       WHEN 0 THEN address
       ELSE        SUBSTR(address, 1, sep1 - 1)
       END AS address1,
       CASE 
       WHEN sep1 = 0 THEN NULL
       WHEN sep2 = 0 THEN SUBSTR(address, sep1 + 1)
       ELSE               SUBSTR(address, sep1 + 1, sep2 - sep1 - 1)
       END AS address2,
       CASE 
       WHEN sep2 = 0 THEN NULL
       WHEN sep3 = 0 THEN SUBSTR(address, sep2 + 1)
       ELSE               SUBSTR(address, sep2 + 1, sep3 - sep2 - 1)
       END AS address3,
       CASE 
       WHEN sep3 = 0 THEN NULL
       WHEN sep4 = 0 THEN SUBSTR(address, sep3 + 1)
       ELSE               SUBSTR(address, sep3 + 1, sep4 - sep3 - 1)
       END AS address4,
       CASE 
       WHEN sep4 = 0 THEN NULL
       ELSE               SUBSTR(address, sep4 + 1)
       END AS address5
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         address,
         INSTR(address, CHR(30), 1, 1) AS sep1,
         INSTR(address, CHR(30), 1, 2) AS sep2,
         INSTR(address, CHR(30), 1, 3) AS sep3,
         INSTR(address, CHR(30), 1, 4) AS sep4
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, ADDRESS) AS
SELECT 1000000, 'Xxxxx Xxxxx'||CHR(30)||'Xxxxx Xxxx'||CHR(30)||'Xxxxxx xx Xxxxxx' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, '61 Xxxxxxx Xxxx'||CHR(30)||'Xxxxxxx'||CHR(30)||'Xxxx' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1000002, '36 Xxxxx Xxx'||CHR(30)||'Xxxxxxxxx'||CHR(30)||'Xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'||CHR(30)||'Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1000003, 'ABC'||CHR(30)||CHR(30)||CHR(30)||'DEF'||CHR(30)||'HIJ' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | ADDRESS1 | ADDRESS2 | ADDRESS3 | ADDRESS4 | ADDRESS5 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1000000 | Xxxxx Xxxxx | Xxxxx Xxxx | Xxxxxx xx Xxxxxx | *null* | *null* |
> | 1000001 | 61 Xxxxxxx Xxxx | Xxxxxxx | Xxxx | *null* | *null* |
> | 1000002 | 36 Xxxxx Xxx | Xxxxxxxxx | Xxxxxxxxxxxxxx | Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx | *null* |
> | 1000003 | ABC | *null* | *null* | DEF | HIJ |

If you did want to use (slower) regular expressions then:

```sql
SELECT id,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(address, '(.*?)('|| CHR(30) || '|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS address1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(address, '(.*?)('|| CHR(30) || '|$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1 ) AS address2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(address, '(.*?)('|| CHR(30) || '|$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1 ) AS address3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(address, '(.*?)('|| CHR(30) || '|$)', 1, 4, NULL, 1 ) AS address4,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(address, '(.*?)('|| CHR(30) || '|$)', 1, 5, NULL, 1 ) AS address5
FROM   table_name
```

Which outputs the same.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5e27f806f0fc06f69acf253d179dea0a)*